# React.js: Set time limit for axios to wait for a response

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to set a time limit for an `axios` request to wait for a response

For example, I fired a request from the client then I would like to set the system to wait for only 8 seconds then show a request time out

Kindly see my `axios` request below

```
executeJwtAuthenticationService(username, password) {
    return axios.post(`${API_URL_LOCAL}`, {
      username,
      password,
    });
  }
```

How would I pattern it similar to this?

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user',
  timeout: 8000, // Let's say you want to wait at least 8 seconds
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
})
```

Comment: Is there an issue with it? What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config Is setting a timeout not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you trying to implement your `axios.post` request with the inline version, so you just have to know, **it will take configs as a separate object**.

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
axios.post(`${API_URL_LOCAL}`, {
  username,
  password,
}, {
  timeout: 8000
});
```

**NOTE:** For more information you can read [this](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-order-of-precedence).

Answer (score 1):

Try Promise.race:

```
executeJwtAuthenticationService(username, password) {
  const timeoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      resolve('It took too long...');
    }, 8000);
  });

  const request = axios.post(`${API_URL_LOCAL}`, {
    username,
    password,
  }); 

  return Promise.race([timeoutPromise, request]);
}
```

You'll probably want to add a similar promise timeout to 'catch' in case response takes long time and fails in the end.
Read about race on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)